# .htaccess gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please help me regarding this issue. I just want to

1. Remove .php extension from my files, which is very well done by this
   code.
2. Convert complex php urls to seo friendly urls.

My htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search_contents/([0-9]+) search_contents.php?txt_search_contents=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: "Convert complex php urls to seo friendly urls" is not a requirement, please reformulate the question and provide examples. For the 500 internal server error, also provide more information, logs, filesystem structure and URL, as a minimum...

Comment: just want to enable clean urls like website.com/search_contents.php?txt_search_contents=132 to website.com/search_contents/132

Comment: Are those `<br/>`'s actually in the htaccess file?

Comment: where is your search_contents.php file? is it in root of your directory?

Comment: @WilliamIsted Isted Nope. I just added that here for clarity not knowing that is not needed. My mistake.

Comment: @HarshSanghani yes search_contents.php file is in root of my server.

Comment: @MImranKhan Can you please try my answer once?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^search_contents/([0-9]+)$ search_contents.php?txt_search_contents=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I have tried it in namecheap and arvixe servers but same results. Found nothing in error-log as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your search_contents.php is at the root of your project directory then try the following :-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search_contents/(.*)$ search_contents.php?txt_search_contents=$1 [L,R=301]
```

If it is in any folder then try the following :-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search_contents/(.*)$ myfolder/search_contents.php?txt_search_contents=$1 [L,R=301]
```

1) I have added `RewriteBase`

2) `([0-9]+)` to `(.*)`, Allow all the parameters instead of only numbers If you required this you can change to number.

It may help you.

Comment: Thanx for your kind reply buddy but it didnt work :-( search_contents.php is in root directory but it includes another php file from a subdirectory which accepts get variable and retrieve data from database.

Comment: @MImranKhan can You please just remove that code of file include, and check its worked or not?

Comment: So we came to know what is the actual issue?

Comment: can you please try one more time with updated answer?

Comment: Ya its still show the same error bro."The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: @MImranKhan now I need to see you code, If you can then ask me I will solve it no issue

Comment: Yes bro i did exactly the same as you told me.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your rules here: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/